# hashicorp consul is not publishing all the metrics

Tags: consul, consul-kv

consul isn't publishing all the metrics defined in their document, from https://www.consul.io/docs/agent/telemetry.html#transaction-timing, it shows only `raft` metrics but not `txn` `kvs`, has anyone observed this problem?

Command to enable prometheus style metrics:

```
consul agent -dev -hcl 'telemetry{prometheus_retention_time="24h" disable_hostname=true}'
```

watch metrics:

```
watch -n 1 -d "curl -s localhost:8500/v1/agent/metrics?format=prometheus|grep -v ^# | grep -E 'kvs|txn|raft'"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Metrics will be exported only if they are available, i.e. if there are no transactions or KV store operations, then you will not see these metrics in the output.

I have managed to see `kvs` metrics in the example you have provided. While running Consul agent via command in the question, in browser open http://127.0.0.1:8500/ and click on `Key/Value` option in the top list (you should end up here http://127.0.0.1:8500/ui/dc1/kv). Click on `Create` to add new Key/Value pair. After clicking `Save` you should see something like this in the terminal running `watch` command:

```
consul_fsm_kvs{op="set",quantile="0.5"} 0.3572689890861511
consul_fsm_kvs{op="set",quantile="0.9"} 0.3572689890861511
consul_fsm_kvs{op="set",quantile="0.99"} 0.3572689890861511
consul_fsm_kvs_sum{op="set"} 0.3572689890861511
consul_fsm_kvs_count{op="set"} 1
consul_kvs_apply{quantile="0.5"} 2.6777150630950928
consul_kvs_apply{quantile="0.9"} 2.6777150630950928
consul_kvs_apply{quantile="0.99"} 2.6777150630950928
consul_kvs_apply_sum 2.6777150630950928
consul_kvs_apply_count 1
```

If there are no more transactions some of these values will be set to `NaN` value, depends on Prometheus metrics type.

Similarly, to see `txn`, you need to create [Consul Transaction](https://www.consul.io/api/txn.html)

Hope that helps you set up monitoring.

Comment: thanks, I can see `kvs` metrics after doing some kv operations so rest of the metrics will also come as we start using them!